# $n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(1-R_i)\overset{p}{\to}P(R_i=0)$, where $R_i$ is a binary variable

Tags: probability, self-study, expected-value, law-of-large-numbers

Say, $R_i$ $(i=1,2,\ldots,n)$ is a binary variable.

I have an estimator $n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(1-R_i)$.

How can I show $n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(1-R_i)$ converges in probability to $P(R_i=0)$? That is,

$\lim_{n\to \infty}n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(1-R_i)=?$

I know $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(1-R_i)P(1-R_i)=\mathbb E(1-R_i)$.

But is $\lim_{n\to \infty}n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(1-R_i)=\mathbb E(1-R_i)$?

Comment: It's hard to decipher what you're writing about.  You haven't given any relationship between this "binary variable" and a "sample" and the notation "$\mathbb{E}(R_i=0)$" does not make sense according to the usual meanings of random variables and expectations.  Please read your post over and clarify these points.

Comment: It's more straightforward than you're making it.  $\mathbb{E}[1-R_i] = \mathbb{E}[1] - \mathbb{E}[R_i] = 1 - \mathbb{E}[R_i] = 1 - P(R_i = 1) = P(R_i = 0)$.

Comment: @jbowman But I have only the estimator  $n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(1-R_i)$. And I have to show where it converges to?

Comment: The [Weak Law of Large Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Weak_law) states that the sample mean converges in probability to the expected value. (I assume, though you have not stated it, that $R_i$ are IID random variables).

Comment: @josliber $n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(1-R_i)$ is the sample mean of $(1-R_i)$. So $\lim_{n\to \infty}n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(1-R_i)\overset{p}{\to} \mathbb E(1-R_i)$ according to weak law of large number.Thank you. I got the answer.

Comment: And $\mathbb E(1-R_i)=\mathbb E(1)-\mathbb E(R_i)=1-\mathbb E(R_i)=1-P(R_i=1)=P(R_i=0)$. And so $\lim_{n\to \infty}n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(1-R_i)\overset{p}{\to} \mathbb E(1-R_i)=P(R_i=0)$. Thanks @ jbowman too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $R_1, R_2, \ldots, R_n$ are IID Bernoulli random variables. By the [Weak Law of Large Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Weak_law), $n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (1-R_i)$ converges in probability to $\mathbb{E}[1-R_i] = 1 - \mathbb{E}[R_i] = 1 - Pr(R_i = 1) = Pr(R_i = 0)$.